# How do I set ajax responseText to be equal to string?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, responsetext

I have a problem with ajax.responseText in condition where it has to be equal to string which is passed in from php echo from external file,
the thing is that the string seems not to be equal to ajax.responseText,

but if alert(ajax.responseText) it is exactly the string "friend_request_sent"

```
function friendToggle(type,user,elem){
var conf = confirm("Press OK to confirm the '"+type+"' action for user <?php echo $u; ?>.");

if(conf != true){
    return false;
}   
_(elem).innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "friend_system.php");

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

        if(ajax.responseText=="friend_request_sent"){          
            _(elem).innerHTML = 'OK Friend Request Sent';       
        } else if(ajax.responseText == "unfriend_ok"){
            _(elem).innerHTML = '<button onclick="friendToggle(\'friend\',\'<?php echo $u; ?>\',\'friendBtn\')">Request As Friend</button>';       
        } else{        
            alert(ajax.responseText);
            _(elem).innerHTML = 'Try again later';
        }
    }
}
ajax.send("type="+type+"&user="+user);

}
```

now the code im getting from friend_system.php

```
 ...{ 
 echo"friend_request_sent";
 exit();
 }
```

and the ajax js code

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
 x.open( meth, url, true );
 x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
   if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
    return true;    
 }
```

}
the third condition is where it struggles ,it always goes to else, why?

Comment: What does the `ajaxReturn()`-function do? You can also do `console.log(ajax.responseText);` and check if there's any white spaces/line breaks outputted before the text. You can also check the actual response from the server through the browsers network tab (in developer tools).

Comment: That isn't much PHP to go on, should this be a php-related issue. As well as the value and origins of the variable(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check ajax response against any string, it is better to trim the response text

```
request.responseText.trim() === "string"
```

Comment: This may indicate a larger issues such as whitespace before/after an open/close PHP tag.  For example `\n<?php` or `?>\n`  Any content outside of PHP tags will returned in the response.  In this case it doesn't matter much, but certain file/content types can have big issues with these things.